# How to access a variable of a service from an activity

Tags: java, android, service

I understand that in order to access methods of a service from an activity, we should bind the service.

But if we just want to get the value of a variable in the service, can we just access it like so without binding?

```
int myActivityVar = myService.myServiceVar;
```

It works, but I’m not sure if it has any memory leak implications or any other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

- The `Activity` will send a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) to the `Service` to request getting the data.
- The `Service` will register the `BroadcastReceiver`, when receiving a broadcast message from the `Activity`, it will prepare result data and send it back to the `Activity` by using [ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver).

**Implementation**

*MyService.java*

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static final String ACTION_GET_DATA = "ACTION_GET_DATA";
    public static final String EXTRA_RECEIVER = "EXTRA_RECEIVER";
    public static final String EXTRA_DATA = "EXTRA_DATA";

    public static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    public static final int RESULT_FAILED = 0;

    // The data of the Service that the Activity want to access.
    private int myServiceVar = 100;

    private final BroadcastReceiver onGetDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Send result data to the activity
            ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER);
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt(EXTRA_DATA, myServiceVar);
            receiver.send(RESULT_OK, resultData);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(onGetDataReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_GET_DATA));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO: Your code logic goes here.
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
private void getDataFromService() {
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    ResultReceiver receiver = new ResultReceiver(mainHandler) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == MyService.RESULT_OK) {
                int data = resultData.getInt(MyService.EXTRA_DATA);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received data = " + data);
            }
        }
    };

    Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.ACTION_GET_DATA);
    intent.putExtra(MyService.EXTRA_RECEIVER, receiver);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Son Truong, but I was wondering why a simple "myActivityVar = myService.myServiceVar" works, and what the problems (if any) are.

Comment: @user20191130 Where do you obtain `myService` instance?

Comment: nowhere, it just works; I have a file called myService.java within the same package

Comment: It seems the `myServiceVar` is a static variable inside `myService` class, which explains why you can access it via class not instance. In this case, there is no problem if you just want to get the value directly from Activity. If you want to access non static variables then you can use my solution without implementing bound service.

Comment: Thank you; so if I declare the variables and methods in myService as static, then I can access them from myActivity without having to bind? And also the other way around: if I declare the variables and methods in myActivity as static, then I can access them from myService without having to bind; I've tested it and it works. Any memory leaks or any other issues?

Comment: It based on a real scenario, if the static variables are primitive types like int, float, double, String, then it's fine. But if one of the static variables is a reference type, and this variable keeps a strong reference to Service or Activity, then it might leak your Activity or Service.